# Socket.io delaying some emits and some others not

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

community,

I try to emit messages with socket.io when I press a key on my piano. What I want to do is, that the key-number of the pressed key should be emitted to my frontend and logged with a simple `console.log()`. This is only working half. When I press a piano-key in a specific key-range the key-number is emitted instantly. When I press another piano-key not in this specific working key-range the key-number is emitted like 5-10 seconds after the first press. I read many stackoverflow-issues with '*socket.io emit delay*', but nothing worked for me out.

I even tried to to set the sent data to a static string. But it's the same issue here. The string is only emitted instantly, when I press a piano-key in a specific working key-range.

I tried to

- set the `sendBuffer` to `[]` after a connection and reconnection
- used `{ rememberTransport: false, transports: ['WebSocket'] }` on client and server side
- tried different socket.io-namespaces

This is my code in simple form:

```js
const pianoMidi         = require('easymidi')
const usbDetect         = require('usb-detection')
const ledStrip          = require('../backend/lib/expModules/lightStrip.js')
const colorEffects      = require('../backend/lib/expModules/colorEffects.js')
const express           = require('express')
const bodyParser        = require('body-parser')
const colorAppConfig    = require('../backend/config')
const colorApp          = express()
const pianoServer       = require('http').createServer(colorApp)
const io                = require('socket.io')(pianoServer)
const mainPianoSocket   = io.of('/mainPianoSocket')

// [...]

usbDetect.startMonitoring()
usbDetect.on('add',(device) => { 
    if(device.deviceName === "Digital_Piano") {
        console.log("Piano connected!")

        mainPianoSocket.on('connection', (socket) => {
            console.log('Client connected!')
            // [...]

            const midiInput = new pianoMidi.Input('Digital Piano:Digital Piano MIDI 1 20:0')
            
            midiInput.on('noteon', (msg) => {
                if(msg.velocity > 0 ) {
                    // [...]
                    socket.emit('pianoKeyPress', msg.note)
                
                } else {
                    socket.emit('pianoKeyRelease', msg.note)
                }
            })
        })    
    })
})

pianoServer.listen(colorAppConfig.server.port, "0.0.0.0")
```

**Note**: The `// [...]` is not relevant for the socket.io-connection so I cut it out for this example

The `msg`-object holds some values from the piano-key hit. It also has the key-number (`msg.note`). When I hit a key in the range of key-numbers from 31 (piano-key g0) up to 103 (piano-key g6) the key-number is emitted instantly to the client and is logged with no delay whatsoever. But if I press a piano-key under 31 or above 103 the emitted key takes between 5 to 10 seconds before showing up in the `console.log()` on the client side.

I don't understand why this is happening since `msg.note` of the specific key-range is not any different from the other keys below or above the specific key-range. Maybe you might know what's going on there? I appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance. Best regards.

Comment: intriguing for sure. I recommend you isolate the moving parts. I recommend you mock the `pianoMidi` object so that it emits integers 0-127 in a well defined way (do not use `setTimeout()`). I believe what you'll find is that the code presented here and/or socket.io is not the issue. It is very possible the `// [...]` commented code may be causing the issue here. If you isolate your code and test is as I've suggested, you'll know that with certainty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can't re-define the `pianoMidi`-object so it provides me integers from 0-127 since my whole logic would break. But as you suggested the problem isn't socket.io it appears to be in the `// [...]`-section to be precise, my own function using npm dotstar library (for leds on my piano). The problem might be the `sync()`-function provided by the dotstar library. But I don't understand how it works in detail. Fortunately your sugeestion was right and I was able to solve my problem temporarily. Might be looking into the dotstar-library soon. Best Regards.

Comment: A solution to consider would be to spawn a new process in which that `//[...]` commented code runs. If this code doesn't affect the client directly (only the keyboard), then this would completely solve the problem for the client. I wouldn't know about the keyboard color thing.